# access the array object inside a higher order function

Tags: javascript, arrays, higher-order-functions

I'm trying to access the length of the array on which I'm using a reduce function inside that reduce, but I don't seem to be able to do it, does anyone have any idea if it is possible to access the array object inside any of the higher order functions?

PS: I tried using `this` but to no success;

PSS: I want to calculate the average rating using a reduce function, so I use the reduce to sum all values in the array and divide those same values by the array length, like so:

```
let averageRating = watchList
    .filter(movie => movie.Director === 'Christopher Nolan')
    .map(x => parseFloat(x.imdbRating))
    .reduce((total, current) => total + (current / 'array length'));
```

where 'array length' would be, you guessed it, the array length.

PSSS: Tried

```
var averageRating = watchList
  .filter(movie => movie.Director === 'Christopher Nolan')
  .map(x => parseFloat(x.imdbRating))
  .reduce((total, current, index, arr) => total + (current / arr.length));
```

but the array length keeps changing as the array is being reduced, so it wouldn't work for my purposes.

Comment: Please share some of your code. It's easier to help you out if you have code.

Comment: if you assign it to a var before the reduce and use that?

Comment: i could do that, but i really wanted to find a way to access it inside the reduce, but it doesn't seem possible :(

Comment: **[`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Syntax)** is supplied four parameters: the accumulator, the current array value, its index, and the array itself.  If you give your callback four parameters, that last one will be the array and you can get its length.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
let averageRating = watchList
    .filter(movie => movie.Director === 'Christopher Nolan')
    .map(x => parseFloat(x.imdbRating))
    .reduce((total, current, idx, arr) => total + (current / arr.length));
```

---

### Update

If you're interested in seeing how I would do it in my preferred library, [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com) (disclaimer: I'm one of its principle authors) the code would like like this:

```js
const {pipe, filter, propEq, pluck, map, mean} = R;

const watchList = [{"Director": "Christopher Nolan", "imdbRating": 4.6, "title": "..."}, {"Director": "Michel Gondry", "imdbRating": 3.9, "title": "..."}, {"Director": "Christopher Nolan", "imdbRating": 2.8, "title": "..."}, {"Director": "Christopher Nolan", "imdbRating": 4.9, "title": "..."}, {"Director": "Alfred Hitchcock", "imdbRating": 4.6, "title": "..."}, {"Director": "Christopher Nolan", "imdbRating": 4.6, "title": "..."}];

const averageRating = pipe(
  filter(propEq('Director', 'Christopher Nolan')),
  pluck('imdbRating'),
  map(Number),
  mean
);

console.log(averageRating(watchList));
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

I find this leads to really clean, readable code.

Comment: I tried it, but I needed the array length as a constant and it changes as the array is reduced, so the average is wrong in the end.

Comment: `reduce` does not change the array on its own.  What is changing it?

Comment: That's fine.  I'm still trying to figure out what's happening in your case.  Can you supply details of what's changing your array?  Is it some other data structure (similar to a `NodeList` or `arguments`) that's array-like but not an array?

Comment: You're right, I was just doing some testing and figured that if i didn't give a initialValue of 0 the average would end up double the amount it was supposed to

Comment: just adding the initialValue fixed it for me.

Comment: the data structure is an array of objects

Comment: Oh, that's interesting.  I have to go see why that happens!

Comment: Oh, of course, it starts with the initial value from your list, without dividing it by the length.  That makes perfect sense.

Comment: The `map` is kind of a waste. Let `current` be the object. Saves a cycle.

Comment: i just didn't want to use dot notation to access the rating inside the reduce, i thought it would get a bit clustered so i mapped beforehand

Comment: @Rudie: It is certainly likely to be less performant, but the code is cleaner.  Choosing between those can be difficult.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
let averageRating = watchList
        .filter(movie => movie.Director === 'Christopher Nolan')
        .map(x => parseFloat(x.imdbRating))
        .reduce((total, current, index, array) => {
            total += current;
            if( index === array.length - 1) {
               return total/array.length;
            } else {
               return total;
            }
        });
```

Comment: this would work as well, but for some reason I wanted to divide each value by the length to take fewer lines, but thanks :D